# Integration Salesforce with Dynamics NAV 2009/2015

Tags: salesforce, integration, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2015, dynamics-nav-2009

We have a client that aims for an integration between Salesforce and Dynamics NAV 2009/2015 (the upgrade to 2015 being planned for later this year).

Now I know what the API on the Salesforce side looks like, but how does that work on the NAV side of things?

What integration mechanism could I use to obtain e.g. contact, account, lead information from NAV 2009/2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd338962(v=nav.80).aspx) to read/modify Nav data. I suppose upgrade of web service based integration will go smoothly between Nav 2009 and Nav 2015.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054999/dynamics-nav-2013-web-application/24096244#24096244) for very basic description of possible integration how it looks from Nav side.

Other options:

1. Access nav data directly via SQL.
2. File exchange through shared folder using Nav application server to create folder listener.