# IOS App communicating with Microsoft Dynamics NAV

Tags: ios, excel, microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav

I'm trying to build a system for a company, which their employess use for timeschedules/payrolls. 
It's supposed to take the input in the app, and post/put it to Microsoft Dynamics NAV. 
I would also like to exctract information from it to, to use in the app.

**MY Question**
Is it possible? I'm not asking for a solution, rather a guideline or previous experience, so I know wether or not this is a project I'm willing to do. 
Somehow I have the idea that it's possible through excel arks - Which I know Navision reads.

Comment: Depends on version of Nav

Comment: Anyway see if this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980160/integration-salesforce-with-dynamics-nav-2009-2015/27982193#27982193

Comment: It's NAV 2009 R2 - Which doesn't use Web Services as far is I understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Web Services in NAV 2009 R2 to connect between an external system and NAV. I'd recommend this over, say, direct SQL access or Flat File transfers.

There is some [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355398.aspx) that might help you get started.

In newer versions of NAV (NAV 2013 specifically) they introduced the concept of Time Sheets, and in NAV 2016 the Phone Client. This may also give you what you need (albeit with an upgrade), without building or maintaining an external application.

Just note that there are specific licensing restrictions around "multiplexing" - e.g. building a web app to access & modify NAV data to get around licensing restrictions. Check out the [NAV license terms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn892088(v=nav.90).aspx);

> In addition to the server software license, you must acquire and
>   assign an Access License to each user that accesses the ERP solution
>   directly or indirectly. You need an Access License for each user that
>   directly or indirectly accesses the ERP solution through a third party
>   application.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Very helpfull answer. 
I think I got what i needed, from one answer - That has to be a first! :'D 
TYVM.

Answer (score 1):

Using Web Services is an option or you can use 3rd Party apps like [MobileNAV](http://www.mobilenav.com/)
and of course you can still upgrade to NAV 2016

Cheers!

Comment: I'm going with Web Services, since the people that have acces to the app I'm making, shouldn't have direct acces to NAV it self - I only need them to send how many working hours they have and sort it in NAV.